# Understanding Gaussian ground state wave functional

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

Right now I'm looking into Gaussian state preparation for quantum simulation of field theories.  These Gaussian states are important because they are the ground state of the free fields of interest.

I'm having trouble understanding/visualizing what these Gaussian states are.  I'm familiar with Gaussian wavepackets from QM that are localized in space, and I've also read in a couple of [places](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) (p. 31) that because the states resulting from the creation operator in the free scalar field aren't normalizable, we often have a superposition of them (the momentum eigenstates) to create a particle that's partially localized in space.

I understand that this is different from the state preparation of Gaussian sites for the ground state.  In the [Jordan-Lee-Preskill paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3633) (p. 5),  they state that "The vacuum (ground) state |vac(0)> of H(0) is a multivariate Gaussian wavefunction in the variables {φ(x)|x ∈ Ω}."  I saw in [other places](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.05708) (p. 13) that this is the ground state wave functional arising from a Hamiltonian that has quadratic terms.

I'm not exactly sure how to think of the φ(x) as variables.  The QFT text that I'm working through introduces the field as a function that assigns an operator to every space-time point.  In the basic QM gaussian case or even just the [general multivariate Guassian case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) it seems like the Gaussian is in the variables of some coordinate system like $x$ so it's easy for me to think about some Gaussian distribution centered in a coordinate space around the mean, but I'm having trouble connecting that picture to the case where we have a field operator that is operator-valued at every space-time point instead of a coordinate.  I also see that in the J-L-P paper φ(x) is referred to as being integer-valued or having a magnitude - is this different from it being operator-valued?

Comment: Are you familiar with the following analogy: put a harmonic oscillator Hilbert space at every point in an $N^d$ lattice. If you give them quadratic couplings, you can find the Gaussian ground state. Each configuration has an amplitude $\psi(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{N^d})$ and this function is a multivariable Gaussian. You can take $N\to \infty$, and indeed this is hard to think about and visualize and plagued with questions like "in what sense does the limit exist". But that is sometimes a useful point of view: it's regular QM, where every field configuration has an amplitude.

Comment: So in this case, if we had a lattice with just one point, how does this reduce to a one-dimensional Gaussian?  We have $\psi(\phi_1)$, with $\phi_1$ being a field operator?  How does this relate to the overall function $\psi$, and what can we say about "where" the Gaussian is centered because it's a function of a field operator?

Comment: Assuming a Hamiltonian like $H\propto \sum_i p_i^2+\phi_i^2$, the wavefunction has maximum amplitude for zero field configuration, $\phi_i=0$. So the Gaussian is centered around zero field. This is true for one point (one point in space, it's just a harmonic oscillator) or many points. The Gaussian isn't a function of position variables, the Gaussian is a function of the field configuration.

Comment: Thank you that helped! In the usual quantum mechanical Gaussian, we have maximum probability amplitude for the particle to be measured at x = 0; x can take different continuous values and we have a Gaussian distribution based on this.  I understand the QFT analogous case for $\phi_1 = 0$ since this just means no field.  However, I don't know what it would mean for  $\phi_1$ to equal other "values" (in which case the amplitude would be lower than at $\phi_1 = 0$) since it's operator valued and given by an integral over the different momentum modes for the annihilation and creation operators.

Comment: As David said, $\phi_i$ is analogous to $x$. In this case, it doesn't make sense to say for example, that "$\phi_1 = 0$ in the ground state", since the ground state is not an eigenstate of the operator $\phi_1$. What you can say is that the ground state goes as $\psi(\phi) \sim \exp(-\phi^2)$, which has a maximum at $\phi = 0$. This is exactly analogous to what you said about $x$ in the standrard quantum-mechanical harmonic oscillator.